# what is the coordinates in robot_localization

Tags: ros, navigation, robot-localization, coordinates

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Tom/all:
As suggested in robot_localization document and REP 103, the imu data is required to be adhere to frame like "x forward, y left, z up", and odom data  should adhere to frame like "x east, y north, z up" (which is ENU coordinates).
Is that so? The relevant input data should go with the coordinates mentioned above or we need to broadcast transform from imuMsg->frame_id to baselink and odomMsg->frame_id to odom.
By the way, what coordinate should GPS data adhere to ?
I have no idea whether I'm right. I do appreciate it if someone can enlighten it to me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263996/what-is-the-coordinates-in-robot_localization/) by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All the data is transformed into its target frames before being fused. Pose data will get transformed in the frame dictated by the `world_frame` parameter, and twist data will get transformed into the frame dictated by the `base_link_frame` parameter.

GPS data should adhere to the standards in the [sensor_msgs/NavSatFix](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/NavSatFix.html) message.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0